# Saved GORM domain object not showing up in mysql

Tags: mysql, grails, grails-orm

I have a Message object that has log entries that are added as the message is processed.

Domain class Message has:

```
SortedSet messageLogEntries
static hasMany = [messageLogEntries: MessageLogEntry]

void addLogEntry(String entry) {
    def mle = new MessageLogEntry(logEntry: entry)
    this.addToMessageLogEntries(mle)
    this.save(failOnError: true, flush: true)
    log.debug(entry)
}
```

I can step through the code the entry is created and saved and allocated an id but when I query the database in MySql the entry is not there.

This was working but is not since I converted from mysql 5.5 to 5.6.10

Please help.

Comment: What SQL is being used? Add `logSql = true` to your dataSource to get this information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this code is being executed inside a Hibernate transaction, you will not see it in the DB until the transaction is committed. Are you running this code inside an integration test or from a transactional execution stream (e.g. a service)?

Comment: Just a heads up, this should really be a comment under his question. If you are asking for more information from the OP, then it isn't considered an answer.

Comment: According to http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/services.html services are wrapped in a transaction. The code is called inside a service. Thanks Gerardo.

Comment: @grantmc I didn't have the required rep to actually post a comment. Either way, I consider it an answer since I'm explaining why something does not show up in the DB under a transactional execution stream, and so has the OP.